# Angular ui-view load slowly

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Is there a fadeIn effect for loading your `ui-view`?

Because sometimes the images are loading a bit slowly.

Comment: Do you have an example of your code?

Comment: I thust have `<main ui-view></main>`, this is the code for angular-ui-router. The content wilt load inside this code but i wanne have a Fadein effect.

Comment: Please see the answer below - basic example for `ui-view` fade in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `ngAnimate` as a dependency to your Angular application (or read https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate)

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-animate.min.js"></script>  
or 
npm install --save angular-animate@X.Y.Z
```

Add `ngAnimate` as a dependency to your application like this:

```
angular
    .module('app', ['ui.router', 'ngAnimate'])
```

Add a `CSS` class to your `ui-view`

```
<div ui-view class="main"></div>
```

Animate with `CSS`

```
.main.ng-enter {
    transition: 0.25s;
    opacity: 0;
}
.main.ng-enter-active {
    opacity: 1;
}
.main.ng-leave {
    transition: 0.25s;
    opacity: 1;
}
.main.ng-leave-active {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

[See JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DaanDeSmedt/oov2xkfs/)

Answer (score 1):

I just add a simple css class to the global css and apply it to the component. This doesn't require `ngAnimate`.

```
.myapp-fade-in {
  /* make things invisible upon start */
  opacity: 0;
  /* call our keyframe named fadeIn, use animation ease-in and repeat it only 1 time */
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn ease-in 1;
  -moz-animation: fadeIn ease-in 1;
  animation: fadeIn ease-in 1;

  /* this makes sure that after animation is done we remain at the last keyframe value (opacity: 1)*/
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode:forwards;
  -moz-animation-fill-mode:forwards;
  animation-fill-mode:forwards;

  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.2s;
  -moz-animation-duration: 0.2s;
  animation-duration: 0.2s;
}
```

Comment: Yea you are right - but this approach is only for initial load ... Not when pages / states changes. Not really flexible in my opinion if you want to go any further with animation.